# I use .appendChild but after I refresh it is gone. How can I keep it there without using cookies? So multiple devices will see the same thing?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, web-development-server

I am making a todo-list in javascript but whenever I add something into this list and then refresh, it is gone. How can I make it able to save, and I don't want to use cookies and would like to use this todo list across multiple devices with the todo list saving. For example, is there a way to add a  container directly into my html instead of through my browser? I know of the .appendChild but that adds it only to the browser and it does not save. I need to do this without cookies.

Recreate this problem:

1. copy and paste the code below into a .html
2. open it up through your browser.
3. add a todo into the input box, for example "throw out the trash"
4. add a due date for this todo.
5. click the "Add Todo" button.
6. Refresh the page.

My code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Practice </title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <input id="todo-title" type="text" />
  <input id="date-picker" type="date" />
  <button onclick="addTodo();">Add Todo</button>
  
  <div id="todo-list"></div>
  
  <script>
    const todos = [{
      title: 'Get groceries',
      dueDate: '2021-10-04'
    }, {
      title: 'Wash car',
      dueDate: '2021-02-03'
    }, {
      title: 'Make dinner',
      dueDate: '2021-03-04'
      
      }];
    //todos.push('another todo'); //Adds to an array
    
    render();
    
    function addTodo(){
      const textbox = document.getElementById('todo-title');
      const title = textbox.value;
      
      const datePicker = document.getElementById('date-picker');
      const dueDate = datePicker.value;
      todos.push({
        title: title,
        dueDate: dueDate
      });
      
      render();
    }
    
    function render(){
      //reset list
      document.getElementById('todo-list').innerHTML = '';
      
      todos.forEach(function(todo){
        const element = document.createElement('div');
        element.innerText=todo.title + ' is due by ' + todo.dueDate;
        const todoList = document.getElementById('todo-list');
        todoList.appendChild(element);
      });
    }
    
    //todos.pop(); //Remove's the last string of an array
  </script>
  
  <!--<div id="counter">0</div>
  <button onclick="addCount();">Up</button>
  <button onclick="removeCount();">Down</button> -->
  
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to make the todo-list save after refreshing. What resulted was the todo disappearing.

Comment: you need backend (server-side) code that saves this information to a database when you add a todo (after you hook your front-end code up to it), as well as to retrieve that from the database on load. Such persistent storage across devices obviously cannot be done in the browser alone.

Comment: How long do you want this to persist? You could try local storage or indexedDB to keep it within the user;s browser "locally" but, otherwise, as Robin Zigmond wrote, you'd need to store the data at the server in order to restore a user's previous session; but, then, you'd have to have a way to identify each unique user. A somewhat "ridiculous" approach that I used for my own work was to download the indexedDB data to local disk and upload it again later but all through user interaction. It can work but I don't think that is what you had in mind.

Comment: Thank you Gary and Robin Zigmond, would you happen to have any tutorial on this backend code for storing the content? If you did that would be much appreciated if you could send it here.             Also, by backend what Lang would that be? Like would Javascript or even something like python work? Thanks!!

Comment: I'm just an amateur but I'm pretty sure it depends on what languages are available on your hosting server. I've used only shared hosting that offers PHP and MySQL / MariaDB. You'll need the PHP to handle the incoming requests and the database to store the information; so, you'll have to learn the database "language" also. Of course, there may be many options for both, depending on your hosting software. If your server has node.js then your back-end language would be JS also and I think it uses MongoDB; but PHP may be easier to learn and available on most hosts. Documentation at php.net.

Comment: You can also practice all of this locally using LAMP if on Linux or WAMP if on Windows. I've used only LAMP and you can build your PHP and database scripts locally before ever put it on a server.  Depending upon where you get it, there may be other options for languages like Perl and maybe even Python, I'm not certain. I use Manjaro Linux and it's all in the repository for installation; so, I don't know of any one source from which to download it over another. I didn't find it to be a minor task, for there is a learning curve to all of this but, of course, it's all doable.